# Which microscopy technique is for wet condition?

Tags: optics, experimental-technique, microscopy

I am searching for a microscopy technique in wet conditions. It must be possible to see through the specimen. ESEM is good but can't see through. TEM needs high vacuum which will boil away water. The specimen is embedded inside a gel. The size of the specimen is between 0.5 µm and 20 µm.

Comment: Kevin, I was going to mention confocal as in [Lionel's answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/91191/26076) but it may be a little coarse for your specimens. So I would recommend that you should look at some superresolution techniques like STED, STORM or structured illumination that can be used together with a confocal system. I give a summary as well as a few links in [my answer here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/89447/26076).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I will take a good look at those technique.

Answer (score 3):

[Confocal microscopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confocal_microscopy) or [two-photon microscopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_excitation_microscopy). Anything with electron is probably not going to work, and neither is AFM, so you're limited to optical or X-ray.

Comment: +1 I was going to mention confocal but it may be a little coarse for the OP's specimens. So I would recommend that Kevin might look at some superresolution techniques like STED, STORM or structured illumination that can be used together with a confocal system. I give a summary as well as a few links in [my answer here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/89447/26076).